Explain the benefit of streaming file data when savings to database in Microsoft example code?
I am looking for the best solution to upload large files to a MySQL database via an ASP.NET Core Web App using Entity Framework Core.
I am looking at the Microsoft documentation *here, but I am struggling to see the benefit of streaming where uploading to a database, and therefore looking for an answer as to why this is suggested in the documentation...
Further down I have copied the entire example controller endpoint example for uploading to the database using EF Core (note FileHelpers.ProcessStreamedFile uses a MemoryStream), but immediately below are the lines which confuses me as it would appear that the entire file is already fully streamed into variable streamedFileContent as it is then used to set the Content property...
Surely, this will have could have a huge impact on the web server resources for large file sizes as the stream will be held in memory?
var file = new AppFile()
    {
        Content = streamedFileContent,
        UntrustedName = untrustedFileNameForStorage,
        Note = formData.Note,
        Size = streamedFileContent.Length, 
        UploadDT = DateTime.UtcNow
    };

_context.File.Add(file);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

If that is correct, I'm struggling to see the benefit of streaming here? ...and seems contrary to the benefit stated in the referenced documentation:

Streaming reduces the demands for memory or disk space when uploading files.

Please NOTE: I am aware that storing large files in relational databases isn't best practice, but that is not the question I am asking (no file storage available to developer).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-8.0#upload-large-files-with-streaming
Entire example method from above docs
[HttpPost]
[DisableFormValueModelBinding]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadDatabase()
{
    if (!MultipartRequestHelper.IsMultipartContentType(Request.ContentType))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("File", 
            $"The request couldn't be processed (Error 1).");

        // Log error

        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    // Accumulate the form data key-value pairs in the request (formAccumulator).
    var formAccumulator = new KeyValueAccumulator();
    var trustedFileNameForDisplay = string.Empty;
    var untrustedFileNameForStorage = string.Empty;
    var streamedFileContent = Array.Empty<byte>();

    var boundary = MultipartRequestHelper.GetBoundary(
        MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(Request.ContentType),
        _defaultFormOptions.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit);
    var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, HttpContext.Request.Body);

    var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();

    while (section != null)
    {
        var hasContentDispositionHeader = 
            ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse(
                section.ContentDisposition, out var contentDisposition);

        if (hasContentDispositionHeader)
        {
            if (MultipartRequestHelper
                .HasFileContentDisposition(contentDisposition))
            {
                untrustedFileNameForStorage = contentDisposition.FileName.Value;
                // Don't trust the file name sent by the client. To display
                // the file name, HTML-encode the value.
                trustedFileNameForDisplay = WebUtility.HtmlEncode(
                        contentDisposition.FileName.Value);

                streamedFileContent = 
                    await FileHelpers.ProcessStreamedFile(section, contentDisposition, 
                        ModelState, _permittedExtensions, _fileSizeLimit);

                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
                }
            }
            else if (MultipartRequestHelper
                .HasFormDataContentDisposition(contentDisposition))
            {
                // Don't limit the key name length because the 
                // multipart headers length limit is already in effect.
                var key = HeaderUtilities
                    .RemoveQuotes(contentDisposition.Name).Value;
                var encoding = GetEncoding(section);

                if (encoding == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("File", 
                        $"The request couldn't be processed (Error 2).");
                    // Log error

                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
                }

                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(
                    section.Body,
                    encoding,
                    detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: true,
                    bufferSize: 1024,
                    leaveOpen: true))
                {
                    // The value length limit is enforced by 
                    // MultipartBodyLengthLimit
                    var value = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();

                    if (string.Equals(value, "undefined", 
                        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        value = string.Empty;
                    }

                    formAccumulator.Append(key, value);

                    if (formAccumulator.ValueCount > 
                        _defaultFormOptions.ValueCountLimit)
                    {
                        // Form key count limit of 
                        // _defaultFormOptions.ValueCountLimit 
                        // is exceeded.
                        ModelState.AddModelError("File", 
                            $"The request couldn't be processed (Error 3).");
                        // Log error

                        return BadRequest(ModelState);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Drain any remaining section body that hasn't been consumed and
        // read the headers for the next section.
        section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
    }

    // Bind form data to the model
    var formData = new FormData();
    var formValueProvider = new FormValueProvider(
        BindingSource.Form,
        new FormCollection(formAccumulator.GetResults()),
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    var bindingSuccessful = await TryUpdateModelAsync(formData, prefix: "",
        valueProvider: formValueProvider);

    if (!bindingSuccessful)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("File", 
            "The request couldn't be processed (Error 5).");
        // Log error

        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    // **WARNING!**
    // In the following example, the file is saved without
    // scanning the file's contents. In most production
    // scenarios, an anti-virus/anti-malware scanner API
    // is used on the file before making the file available
    // for download or for use by other systems. 
    // For more information, see the topic that accompanies 
    // this sample app.

    var file = new AppFile()
    {
        Content = streamedFileContent,
        UntrustedName = untrustedFileNameForStorage,
        Note = formData.Note,
        Size = streamedFileContent.Length, 
        UploadDT = DateTime.UtcNow
    };

    _context.File.Add(file);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Created(nameof(StreamingController), null);
}

I have tried debugging and it would appear that streamedFileContent byte array is complete during the database save

I believe you are correct. byte[] values are always stored in memory, and it appears that the MS example code is indeed reading the entire file into memory before saving it, which completely removes the benefits of streaming in the first place. If you have a MySql API that can take a stream, then using that instead of byte[] would be better.

MySQL doesn't have a streaming API. In SQL Server streaming is beneficial because the driver doesn't have to send a huge blob as a single parameter to the server. Which will have to keep that huge blob in memory until all of it is received instead of starting to write it to disk

This was discussed in MySqlConnector's Github repo (ie the real open source provider, not Oracle's hobbled one). The problem is that MySQL's protocol requires a fixed message length, so streaming isn't possible.

@StephenCleary do you know which .Net MySQL API's have streaming?  Thanks

@RyanO: Nope. From the comments above, it sounds like it doesn't support streaming.

A working thought I will mull over the weekend is to alter the example to use a stored procedure which appends bytes to an existing stub record.  My thoughts are that I will save each stream section to the database as it is streamed, rather storing in the byte array.
Would be interested to know if this sounds like a terrible idea.

Maybe Microsoft docs talk about MS SQL and author expects the same for MySQL. MySQL is 50 years after MS SQL.

Outside the remit of the original question regarding streaming.  But for anyone else having issues saving large amounts of data to MySQL, I have adopted a chuncking strategy.  Instead of storing a largeblob with all of the data. I have a databasefilepart table which stores the file in chunks.  Ignoring how the Web App is handling streams, I have found anecdotally storing many smaller parts e.g. 50kb is much faster at being persisted than larger chunks e.g. 1mb.

Cannot edit my previous comment to save face.  My advocation for smaller chunking parts being faster at being persisted to MySQL seems to be irrelevant as further testing implies it is much of a muchness until your chunk sizes are so big it makes chunking pointless.  On the other hand, splitting into smaller chunks does facilitate better streaming of the file out of the database via an endpoint because it can start streaming the response with the first small chunk.
